# Changing trends in number of questions by tag - how can we interpret these?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see in https://stackoverflow.com/tags that [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag is about to surpass [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) in the leadership of total number of questions.

Currently these are the figures:

```
asked      |  today  | this week  |  total
-------------------------------------------
c#         |    773  |    4175    |  640738
Java       |    973  |    5633    |  639832
Javascript |   1081  |    5903    |  613446
PHP        |    808  |    4836    |  579516
```

In the same list it is also interesting to see how [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) is growing way faster than others (now it is 9th), while for example [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) is practically flat (just 188 questions this week).

Does all of this symbolize any movement in the tendencies of the programming?

---

Here some graphs created with [Question Count or Score growth over time by tag comparison](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201360/question-count-or-score-growth-over-time-by-tag-comparison):

c# - java - javascript - php ([show plot](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201360/question-count-or-score-growth-over-time-by-tag-comparison?ShowScore=0&Tag1=java&Tag2=c%23&Tag3=javascript&Tag4=php#graph))

> [image]

Android - iphone - ios ([show plot](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201360/question-count-or-score-growth-over-time-by-tag-comparison?ShowScore=0&Tag1=android&Tag2=iphone&Tag3=ios&Tag4=NA#graph))

> [image]

Comment: my interpretation is that means Java sucks more and more, and soon it is going to suck even more than C#

Comment: maybe there's a large influx of newbies who don't know any better

Comment: It means Windows Phone still attracts less developers than Android. *runs away*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi that is actually a plausible explanation.

Comment: @usr, [indeed](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/ha-ha-only-serious.html).

Comment: A lot of users of Android and Web nowadays. More devices using Java probably than C/C++ code IMHO

Comment: Meaningful numbers would probably include a nice graphical representation of percentage per day or so

Comment: Maybe Java is also distorted by Java 8 being out freshly. And it is heavily used as entry language in university/highschool courses. And then if the language itself is cumbersome then probably the number of questions is higher without more real usage. So the relative positions I doubt but if someone wants to get a good overview what might be useful techniques - just pick from the top 30 tags and it should not be too wrong. For example: How can one ask almost 80k questions about JSON? It's pretty straight forward. But then the tag is probably just a side tag in questions.

Comment: Maybe Java is harder to learn then C#....

Comment: How can a discussion NOT be primarily opinion based? :shrug:

Comment: @PlasmaHH just updated with some graphs :)

Comment: @fedorqui: excellent! the iphone curve is very intresting

Comment: At this moment, [tag:javascript] is in the lead, and [has just passed 1m questions!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311929/congrats-on-1m-javascript-questions)

Comment: This is a really fun SEDE query to play with! Here in the far off year of 2021, [tag:javascript] is still [pulling away even farther](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHvyE.png), and sits comfortably beyond the 2mil mark.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Does all of this symbolize any movement in the tendencies of the programming?

Yes, towards mobile platforms, particularly Android and mobile Web.

Over 80,000 [Android questions are also tagged Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+java). That's over twice as many questions as [windows-phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone), [windows-phone-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7), and [windows-phone-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8) combined, so there's really not as much pressure in the mobile development space driving C# questions (yet).

Comment: It's interesting to note that the 5th most popular tag _is_ Android. Alone, that must influence the number of tags on other technologies used with Android development (such as Eclipse, sqlite, etc.)

Comment: @lilbyrdie Yes, it does appear to be giving those tags a substantial boost. 25% of all Eclipse questions are also tagged Android, as are 40% of SQLite questions. (Quite a few in both groups are unanswered, too.)

Comment: I'm wondering of those "quite a few" that are unanswered are that way because they're bad newb questions, or if there's some other reason.

Comment: @Gabe Some of both. Since they're in the Android tag, it's a safe guess that a lot of them are bad newb questions. I hate to say it, but I've noticed that a lot of people are trying to learn how to make an Android app without first bothering to learn how to program.

Comment: So maybe the interesting metric is question (or all) upvotes by tag rather than questions by tag.

Comment: @Gabe Probably a combination would be better, like upvotes/posts. (I've been using unanswered question % as a very rough metric for tag quality.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard I definitely see a lot of non-programmers trying to learn Android. Although not as bad, there are plenty of mobile developers that don't have any relational database experience and get forced into sqlite development, and other such technologies. That increases the likelihood of "newb" questions on some topics, even if they aren't complete "newb" programmers. (Although it might call into question the breadth of their CS courses...)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can interpret SO activity trends as indicators of the popularity or immediate relevance of programming languages (or other tags/topics).  It is more likely SO activity trends reflect on the popularity of SO itself within the communities associated with the topics.

At any rate it would be extremely difficult to separate the concerns enough to draw meaningful conclusions.  Is the number of Java programmers on the rise?  Has SO answered so many C# questions that there is little need for new ones to be asked?  Is Java so much more confusing than C# (or vice versa) that more questions need to be asked?  Are existing SO participants switching from C# to Java or are new participants joining to talk about Java?  Have SO participants become so hooked on the experience that they undertake new topics just to build them up on SO?

I don't think those can be untangled, but I'm sure lots of people would enjoy the attempt or at least enjoy building and talking about tools with which to make an attempt.  Hmm, maybe if I try to link heavy posters on the maths sites to trending questions on meta I can build a tool to find the people to build the tools...

Comment: Great Answer. Pity I can't give Bounties here :)

Answer (score 4):

If you look at [Google trends data](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=c%23%2C%20.net%2C%20VB%2C%20Java%2C%20Android&cmpt=q), there is a clear decline in Java searches over time. C# and .NET have remained stable but the volume is lower than that of Java. I believe that the rise in SO questions about Android is what is causing the uptick, because Android has a lower cost barrier to entry than iPhone.  As Bill the Lizard pointed out, the questions are generally of a lower quality and often show a lack of a programming background.

I don't want to get flamed but I am curious about how the [court decision against Google](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_v._Google) will affect Google's use of Java.

Comment: That's because even a lot of Java developers can use Android as a tag, and the Android documentation tends to be better formatted, so...

Comment: There are two separate groups within the Java base: Server side and Android (I know that some people are still using Swing and there is some renewed interest in JavaFX but that is a very small group compared to the other two.  I suspect that a search would show that Tomcat+JavaEE trending down but still a very large group.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Yup, the Android docs are simply *amazing* compared to the Oracle ones...