# How to compare tags by question-count over time?

Tags: support, tags

I recently noticed that there are more questions tagged with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) than with [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) (659K vs. 655K).

IIRC, in the early days of Stack Overflow, this used to be the other way around. Is there a way to see historical trends in questions with a specific tag?

Comment: Related: [Changing trends in number of questions by tag - how can we interpret these?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254836/changing-trends-in-number-of-questions-by-tag-how-can-we-interpret-these). Funny I wanted to edit my original post showing the differences, this post shows how!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Here's a query that **shows the cumulative totals**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201360/question-count-or-score-growth-over-time-by-tag-comparison).
You can:

- Compare up to 4 tags.
- Plot either the cumulative question count or the total score per tag.

For [C# and Java, the plot shows](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201360/question-count-or-score-growth-over-time-by-tag-comparison?ShowScore=0&Tag1=java&Tag2=c%23&Tag3=NA&Tag4=NA#graph) that Java overtook C#, question-count wise, in April 2014:

[(Click for a larger image)

[image: Questions over time for C# and Java]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQzeh.gif)

Another interesting measure is the cumulative score for a tag.  
Here's [the cumulative score for C# and Java][5]:

[(Click for a larger image)

[image: Score over time for C# and Java]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC00m.gif)

---

---

---

A few upvoters asked about comparing Java and Android. [Here is that plot](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201625/c-java-and-android-growth-over-time-comparison?ShowScore=0#graph):

[image: Java V Android]

And one [comparing Java and Swing](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201623/c-java-and-swing-growth-over-time-comparison?ShowScore=0#graph):

[image: Java V Swing]

Comment: I have a feeling that recent popularity of Java is caused by Android. Maybe it is worth adding chart with `Java` `C#` and `Java questions without Android tag`?

Comment: The higher C# score is obviously caused by Jon Skeet.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat, The plot is for **Question** score. [Jon Skeet only *asked* 10 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A22656+[c%23]+is%3Aquestion) -- for a total score of 2,242. Or maybe you meant that Jon's upvotes made the difference - And it's true that Jon was way better about upvoting than many people. But [Jon only voted on questions 2,227 times](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet#user-panel-votes) and it's unlikely that those were all upvotes on C# questions.  At most, Jon made about 3% of the difference on the cumulative scores of those two tags.

Comment: @Pshemo, added the plot. It shows a massive growth in Android compared to the acceleration in Java.  It neither proves nor disproves your conjecture.

Comment: @BrockAdams I was trying to make a joke.

Answer (score 17):

Sure - just write yourself a little query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201292#graph

[image: questions per month in C# and Java]

That's just questions per month, not the cumulative totals - calculating when the number of Java questions first surpassed C# questions is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: **psst** compare the integrals :)

Comment: @secretformula: Better not integrals, they would be wrong. You see the connecting lines? Plain sums for n = -infinity to time is correct.

Comment: More and more questions per month, but less and less content/quality per question..