# Thanks a million, Jon Skeet

Tags: discussion, reputation

Yesterday, [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) hit **1,000,000 reputation on Stack Overflow**.

[image: profile for Jon Skeet on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

A million rep. The achievement quite frankly boggles the mind. I've been thinking about this meta post for days, trying to figure out how to describe the significance of this accomplishment. I can't really find the words, but fortunately I don't really have to. I'm willing to bet that there's not a single person here perusing meta that hasn't been affected, however indirectly, by Jon's support and dedication to this community. So I can't really figure out how to thank Jon enough, but maybe together we can all do it justice.

Julia and Nick from the Data Team have chronicled his Stack Overflow career in detail [over on the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet/). We’ve also got plans in the coming weeks to celebrate Jon’s achievement and thank him for his hard work and dedication to helping his fellow programmers and the Stack Overflow community. Part of the celebration will include an IRL Q&A with Jon himself, an opportunity to sit down with him, thank him for everything he’s done, and learn more about him both as a pillar of the programming community and as an all-around kind, generous, and helpful human.

The Q&A will be recorded and shared with you all. Since Stack Overflow is nothing without the community that runs it, it’s only right that we put the question to you. (Meta is a Q&A site, after all; I've got to end with a question.) So: Are you one of the millions of people he’s reached with his expertise and generosity? Or is there something you’ve always wanted to know about him or his career (while respecting his privacy, of course)? **What would you like to ask or share with Jon**, either here in text or conveyed in person when he sits down with us in a few weeks?

Comment: As a c# developer, I also want to thank you! You are guilty of a big part of my learning process. And respect for doing nearly a fulltime job in sharing knowledge for free! :)

Comment: A related post [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339819/465053) which was speculating that he will cross the milestone somewhere in July this year. He did it 6 months ahead of time :P

Comment: @RBT actually, he's 6 months behind that schedule. That post is from December 2016. OTOH, Jon Skeet is never late, he reaches milestones exactly when he means to.

Comment: @Glorfindel Jon was slacking

Comment: ohh! @Glorfindel My bad. I just saw the `asked 1 year ago` information in right pane and inferred the wrong info. I didn't see the exact time stamp of the question. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: Who's responsible for that steep line in the first graph in the blog? Is that the community user? That can't be a human being...

Comment: Formatting of the 1m rep is weird on badges `1000k` https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1704/casting?userid=22656

Comment: @Glorfindel: No, the milestones come to him.

Comment: @AshleyMedway Seeing this post showing a badge with 1.1m, I thought they fixed it, but according to the linked [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339819/how-to-format-reputation-when-jon-skeet-hits-1-million-rep-next-year?noredirect=1&lq=1) at the right, it seems to be by design :(

Comment: @AshleyMedway I know that, I didn't question the value, but the format

Comment: The Skeet bot just helped me solve a totally unrelated gardening problem! Thank you!

Comment: @Adinia oh right, I follow :)

Comment: My Question to Jon: What are your top 3 [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)?

Comment: One point to note - as there are already 14 "answers" (questions) at the time of writing this comment, I suspect we may not get to them all IRL. I'm happy to write a blog post after the fact covering anything we don't get to during the live Q&A.

Comment: Surely, this should be [meta-tag:featured].

Comment: I'll soon hit 68k, and I really hope you already began to write a post about me hitting 68k.

Comment: @ryanyuyu will be soon! I’ve got a policy I just invented: don’t [feature] anything I post in the middle of the night when there’s no one around to proofread. ;)

Comment: And there's the first "POB" close-vote _*Facedesk*_... Guys, this is an announcement / celebration. This isn't an ordinary question, and sure as hell shouldn't be closed.

Comment: @Cerbrus I didn't/won't vote to close, but will definitely understand people who do. After all, rules are rules and we should obey them. There are many other places that can host this kind of posts. Alternative: Add a tag for "announcements", "celebration" or whatever.

Comment: @Maroun: Then, in my opinion, they're completely missing the point of this post, meta and SE in general. There is no place with the kind of reach meta has. Meta has traditionally been used for announcements like this.

Comment: @Cerbrus As long as our close-votes are consistent, I don't see any problem with that. The problem arises when similar post gets closed because it was posted by non-mod user, and about non-jon-skeet user. Again, I'm not against keeping this post.

Comment: @Maroun: [like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311929/congrats-on-1m-javascript-questions)? That was received pretty well also.

Comment: I'm a simple user. I see Jon Skeet, I click.

Comment: Are people really voting to close this?! Also, this should really be [meta-tag:featured].

Comment: Let's get this post to one million upvotes!

Comment: Skeet bot needs some work.  I just asked it "Why is the sky blue?" and I've spent the last several hours trying to discern the format of the sky so that I could write a LINQ query, before finally giving up in frustration.

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 I asked it "why is water wet?" and while I didn't really understand the response, it seemed so confident and sensible that I'm sure it must have been right in some way.

Comment: @Glorfindel However, if you read the [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339819/how-to-format-reputation-when-jon-skeet-hits-1-million-rep-next-year#comment422655_339819) form Jon he speculates he will hit 1m around this time, it was only Bohemian who got it wrong :)

Comment: Can anyone explain why his rep is >1M but his "reached" total is ~64k? Just curious.

Comment: @nicomp You were probably looking at Jon's [meta profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=topactivity). His [main profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=topactivity) has achieved the rather more impressive 224.4 million people reached!

Comment: Was this post meant to be an AMA like question?

Comment: @Cerbrus The steep line to 40k answers? I imagine that is Gordon Linoff. https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff as he "only" started 6 years ago and has 41K answers and is in the top 10 rep users.

Comment: @Maroun *"As long as our close-votes are consistent"*, ultimately the diamond mods will decide if a question of this type is significant and relevant enough to stay open or be closed, should they decide to weigh in. And I think they will, otherwise we will see a few close-reopen cycles, just because people can...

Comment: Although I'm not a fan of "idolizing" people, I couldn't resist to add the first statement that Jon Skeet ever made on stackoverflow as an (unattributed) quote in my profile. It's nearly always true, so ...

Comment: Why isn't it (as of today) 1.0m?

Comment: Is this going to be one of those meta questions "asked" about Jon Skeet where Jon Skeet comes and answers about himself and still manages to get the [top answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: The network flair was incorrectly used when it should have been the SO flair (Bergi has edited it accordingly now).

Comment: My Question : When do you answer all of following questions?

Comment: Didn't Jon that [already answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362019/thanks-a-million-jon-skeet#comment548881_362019)? @IamtheMostStupidPerson

Comment: @usr2564301 How do you find that how many duplicate question has for that question and how do you know that it is the question which has most duplicates in SO.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson: [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/315074) finds *all* duplicate targets but times out. So I constructed [a custom one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/783358) inquiring for that question alone. I do not know which question has *the* most duplicates, but it sure must be a contender.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339826/7147233

Comment: I actually first came across Jon Skeet by reading his blog. These congratulations are deserved.

Comment: Actually I remember being helped as new C# programmer in the early 2000s by Jon when he was answering C# questions in usenet news. I think it was in microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp Thanks Jon!

Comment: @Cerbrus that steep line is [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff?tab=topactivity), who at the time of me writing this has 41,090 answers.

Comment: In Soviet Russia, 1,000,000 reputation hits Jon Skeet.

Comment: I see that the website is holding up pretty well to Jon's large numbers.  Nice to know we didn't break the internet this time.

Comment: Now there's also a [**Skeet Bot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbkdL.png)! Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet/)!

Comment: You'll look back at this post in two or three years time and laugh at that paltry title! Well done Jon.

Comment: Many of the questions that are suggested until now are already answered, at least to some extent, and particularly in https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/ (just mentioning... it's not possible for *answers* to be "closed as duplicate" ;-) )

Comment: Assuming that Jon Skeet has been hitting the rep limit on upvotes alone every single day since he joined, that earns him about 675,000 points. So this means that accepted answers and bounties make up about 325,800 points. Doing some more math this means that of his 34,000+ answers, about 64% have been accepted as the correct answer. However, you may wish to burn me at the stake because we all know that his answers are immediately accepted when he presses the "Answer This Question" button and begins typing so the 64% is nothing more than a fairy tale.

Comment: So... Did I miss the answers on the blog or are they posted in 6 to 8 weeks?

Answer (score 213):

Question to Jon:

*How do you combine your activity on Stack Overflow with work (/family & hobbies)?*

Comment: To clarify: "How the #!@§%&! do you combine your activity on Stack Overflow with work?"

Comment: I'm more interested in how he manages to work, contribute to SO and *raise a family*. It's super hard for me to balance those three things in my own life and I contribute a *tiny fraction* of what Jon contributes here.

Comment: @meagar: Good point:P slightly updated my answer.

Comment: I thought he'd said somewhere that his employer actively encourages/supports his efforts on SO. (citation needed)

Comment: I'd also like to know if he ever sleeps or if he has some special super power like time travel to find the hours in the day to achieve this

Comment: @Jeutnarg: Yes, but that doesn't tell you anything about how he manages his time.

Comment: Maybe it's an account shared by many people... who knows ([tag:joke]). But yeah it looks very hard to do.

Comment: I want to know how he finds the time to write 34k high quality answers and still has a demanding job and is raising a family. Looks like some sort of time stopping power to me.

Comment: @Magisch maybe he has [Bernard's Watch](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0171980/)

Comment: Probably he keeps his wife busy talking to the Markov model [Ask Skeet Bot](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet/)

Comment: @Magisch One thing which had been very critical to  his success is that he was already done authoring 1st Edition of book `C# in Depth` even before SO got a beta launch. He was already a super champion in C#. SO just became a platform to unleash his craving to share his knowledge. So if somebody who would have started to master C# just to be rank 1 on the day website got launched then he would have found it really really hard. Anyone else would have required double or triple the time to answer same 34K posts. His mastery on the subject has certainly helped him fine tune that work-life balance.

Comment: @Magisch You're right. It's a [well-known fact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9182/286709).

Comment: Waiting for a response from him.

Comment: [I know how he does it](https://media.giphy.com/media/toXKzaJP3WIgM/giphy.gif)

Comment: A while ago Jon commented that he has a very long train commute (2-3hrs) to work and back (like many people living in the London area), and he was answering posts during this time. Also he answers posts during long software builds.

Answer (score 190):

Question to Jon: Who is your Jon Skeet? When you were a beginner, who was your "God of development"? Or, who inspired you the most?

Comment: Jon was never a beginner.  In the beginning, Jon said "Let there be software development," and there was software development.  And Jon saw that it was good.

Comment: @bubbleking is Jon Skeet the Chuck Norris of software development?

Comment: @stannius - You be the judge: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts

Answer (score 120):

Question to Jon:

- How many job offers do you receive per week?

Comment: ... or per second?

Comment: Jon does not get any job offers. Jobs study and prepare themselves for years to be worthy of being considered by Jon Skeet as something that he might work on.

Comment: In a typical week, does he get more job offers or answer more questions?

Comment: The answer is proportional to the number of questions he's answered.

Comment: He receives all of them.

Comment: By law it is mandatory for any job position opened to be offered to Jon Skeet before anyone else.

Answer (score 108):

How do you think Stack Overflow is doing, overall, in its eternal struggles -

- balancing question quality with welcomingness and traffic
- discriminating against low-quality content but not so much so to put people off
- being a repository of knowledge for future readers rather than a one-on-one support forum?

Comment: I think you asked it better than I did (even if we're not asking exactly the same question).

Answer (score 83):

Question to Jon: what [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) (either an existing one or something new) would you think adds the most value to Stack Overflow? Or in other words: what is the functionality you miss the most while using the site?

Answer (score 63):

To Jon:

What is the best guiding advice you've given to a developer, and what is the best guiding advice you've *received*?

Answer (score 52):

To Jon:

What is a notably shocking piece of code you have implemented in order to get a project over the line / to testing which later in review / reflection have laughed about?

Answer (score 47):

To Jon:

What is the answer, or question(?) you're the most proud of here at Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 46):

To Jon:

1. C# is a language with plenty of power. Are there any obstacles for you in the language design - if any - which, while contributing, at the same time are a setback for great things to happen?
2. What concepts, ideas, syntactical features from other languages do you (if you) miss or would want to come to C#?
3. We've seen Rust, Kotlin, Go, Swift emerge. These languages were made to make programming easier and more fun. Do you think C# and its design can withstand the time, or its scalability and flexibility would once give way?

Comment: I think this question is one of my favorites so far!

Comment: Re: *"make programming easier and more fun"*: And safer?

Comment: @PeterMortensen and safer. And faster, cleaner, more flexible. Easier and more fun.

Answer (score 44):

My question to Jon - Are you a morning person or a night owl in your daily routine?

Answer (score 40):

Question to Jon:

What is the biggest lesson you've learned being part of the Stack Overflow community?

Comment: The real question is: what has StackOverflow learned from Jon?

Answer (score 32):

Questions to Jon:

- What do you think is the biggest mistake C# made (if any)?
- What is *the* C# language feature you want to see in the future and why?

Comment: I know one such thing that Jon always wanted that classes in C# should be sealed by default. Inheritableness should be something explicit. Check out his views [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6389417/465053). I *didn't* down-vote you.

Comment: Contrary to this, I have seen C++ class developers making each destructor _virtual_ - irrespective if that class will be used for inheritance. The class would have zero virtual functions!

Comment: Poor poor C#, it can't defend itself. The designers of the language made the mistakes ;)

Comment: @RBT: of course C# would be much better if the `object` class were `sealed`.

Answer (score 30):

My question to Jon:

With the over-saturation of troubleshooting questions on the site, what are some other types of programming questions you'd like to see more of?

- In the same vein, what types of questions do you feel need to be restricted; and what types of questions do you feel are being needlessly shut down or too heavily policed, but asked and answered well could have a far-reaching impact while keeping in the spirit of Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 30):

Question to Jon:

You wrote a blog post about [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and offered the [Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) here on Meta.

After all these years, what would be your top tip to (new) users asking a question? What about answering a question? What makes that a post is deemed useful by the visitors of Q/A pair.

Comment: You think he'll tell us his secret of how to get 1m rep?

Comment: @ThomasWeller You'd have to setup a clone site, really discredit Stack Overflow so people will actually go use it and immediately ban Jon Skeet from it or else you have no chance.

Answer (score 30):

Question to Jon:

- What is one question you wish had been in this list of questions that wasn't?

---

<sup>*(This should probably be asked last.)*</sup>

Answer (score 30):

Aside from congratulations, the one thing I'd like to **share** with Jon is my apologies...

The first question I ever asked on Stack Overflow was back when I had my first internship and my boss was hovering over my shoulder, adamant about some task that he was having me do was completely possible (I think it was something to do with passing values through batch scripts, but I can't remember).

What I do remember is, unfortunately, Jon decided to comment on my post explaining that it wasn't possible to do - which my boss wouldn't accept. This resulted in about a half hour conversation between my typing of my bosses thoughts and a Jon Skeet that was getting more and more annoyed, judging by his/your responses.

So I sincerely apologise for this event that you've probably forgotten about now and thank you for the help you've given me since.

Comment: I assume your boss's fate is something you don't, and never will, speak of.

Comment: Nice story. I can almost feel your boss breathing on my neck. Ugh!

Comment: C'mon, post the *link* to this post (if it still exists, and even if it's "deleted") - that sounds *too* entertaining to omit it :-D

Comment: @Marco13 - I wish I could! Its not a "recently deleted question" and I'm not even sure if the embarrassment made me make a new account anyway

Answer (score 28):

Question to Jon: What's your programming story? In other words, when and how exactly did you become interested programming? What was your first project?

Comment: You mean he does not have a developer story here on SO? What a pity.

Comment: Interested? You mean when was he built and compiled?

Comment: @MacroMan: and if he was taught to sing a song by his instructor.

Answer (score 24):

Question to Jon: how do you personally feel about the fact that you're a Stack Overflow celebrity and get referenced by (user) name at least several times a month on meta, be it in the form of a sort of [Chuck Norris joke](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) or with immense praise?

Assuming you have no problem with it, which post about you did you enjoy more than others?

Comment: Several times a month? Make that "week"...

Comment: " I'm far from the genius programmer that I'm sometimes portrayed as - I feel privileged to have worked with some far smarter people) - but of course the more I say that, the more people think I'm being modest - falsely or otherwise." - https://www.quora.com/Who-is-Jon-Skeet-and-how-did-he-become-famous-on-Stack-Overflow

Comment: @Cerbrus That is only occasionally from what I've seen, I didn't want to make it sound like we're worshipping the guy ;) (well some people...)

Comment: @zze Thanks for sharing; the more relevant quote is *"I've always thought my "fame" on Stack Overflow is a bit overblown, but that doesn't prevent me from enjoying it"*. It's still not exactly the same question, I really do wonder how our constant reaction to his celebrity status affects him.

Comment: In case anyone doesn't know, the top answer on the "Jon Skeet facts" question was posted by Jon Skeet himself.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think you meant _daily_ ;-)

Answer (score 21):

"Do you prefer immediately answering a question over considering it might a duplicate and checking for that first?"

(Based on a number of answers where the question indeed got closed as such.)

Comment: Jon doesn't need to _check_ for duplicates. He'll know. He wrote the answers.

Comment: @Cerbrus: that is indeed why I'd like this answered.

Comment: After thinking it over, can I change My Question to "With one million points on Stack Overflow in one hand and a dollar in the other, can you still buy a cup of coffee?" 

Comment: @usr2564301: I'm pretty sure the answer is "No he couldn't pay if he tried; cups of Java just donate themselves to the Skeet"

Comment: In the past, I have noticed two almost-identical Jon Skeet answers, to duplicate questions.  It appeared that he'd forgotten all about the first answer when he wrote the second one.

Answer (score 17):

I've done a Google search on [Jon](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-34596634) before to try and learn more about him. I had no idea that he also preaches at his church. As such, here is my

Question to Jon:

How (if at all) does your faith tie into the contributions you've made on Stack Overflow?

Comment: That's an interesting one!

Comment: Interesting perhaps, but I think we should be very careful about keeping this subject separate from Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DavidG: [Don't remind me...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295810/do-we-allow-religious-invocations-in-questions-answers)

Comment: @BoltClock Exactly! I'm willing to bet that Jon would like to keep the two worlds very far apart too...

Comment: @DavidG I would argue that we are asking questions directed at Jon Skeet, **NOT** Stack Overflow. In that sense, I fail to see how this question is any different than [the currently highest voted question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362036/8206887)

Comment: @Sudsy1002 Yes, but that question has no controversy at all, this one has literally thousands of years of controversy attached. I've no problem with the question at all, it might even be something I would love to discuss with Jon if I ever had the pleasure to meet him in person, but for this situation... it's dangerous.

Comment: Meh. If there's *anyone* I trust to talk about this in a manner that is not going to piss off anyone reasonable (or make them even remotely uncomfortable or anything) then it's Jon. This is going to be about him, after all, not just Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Pekka웃 It's not Jon I'm worried about, it's everyone else!

Comment: @DavidG OK... I see your point. :) It's ultimately going to be up to him anyway, so we'll see whether he takes it up or not.

Comment: Yeah what @DavidG said. I'm keen on learning from Jon's answer to this myself, but I don't trust the community one bit to handle this maturely.

Comment: Yeah, we all remember what happened with the "Time to take a stand" question...

Answer (score 16):

Does having a celebrity like status on SO make it harder for you to answer new questions, knowing you have a reputation to uphold?

Comment: I imagine it's hard to be wrong, people will see the name and just upvote because Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 13):

Jon, you peaked at almost 800 answers per month. That's beyond my imagination. Did you clone yourself (Skeet-so-phrenic), did you install TPL?

How *on earth* (I assume) did you do it?

Comment: Like: 30 answers per day, meaning 3 answers per hour? Is that a miracle?

Comment: @tkruse Well, not if answering SO questions is a (more than) full-time job. But Jon clearly has got a few other occupations.

Answer (score 12):

Question to Jon (based upon the third row of https://toggl.com/programming-princess):

> How often have you had to save the princess from the castle?

And a follow-up question from [Cerbrus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus) from the comments:

> And how often was the princess in another castle?

Comment: And how often was the princess in another castle?

Comment: Is this a sexual euphemism? 

Comment: https://toggl.com/programming-princess  @Pekka웃 The third panel ;-)

Comment: 34070 answers, that's a load of princesses!

Answer (score 11):

Question to Jon:

How did you discover Stack Overflow? Do you remember what your first impression of this site was?

Comment: The first statement that he ever made here on stackoverflow **might** summarize this (and that's why I cited it in my profile) : The first thing he said on stackoverflow was: **"There's a certain amount of misinformation here."** - I can imagine him skimming through some answers and thinking: "Holy sh!t, what a bunch of incompetent dorks! I *have* to sign up there and put this right!". Just speculation, though...

Comment: @Marco13: now we can accurately date the famous [xkcd "Duty Calls"](https://xkcd.com/386/) to that event in history.

Comment: @usr2564301 Yeah, I also thought about that, but then forgot to add the link ;-)

Answer (score 11):

Do you see yourself coding all the way to retirement, or do you think you might get fed up, or want to do something completely different?

Asking for a friend, obviously...

Answer (score 10):

My questions to Jon:

1. What's the best question you've seen on Stack Overflow?
2. What's the best answer you've seen?

Answer (score 10):

**Questions to Jon**

- If there was one thing you could change about Stack Overflow, or its community, what would it be?
- Have you ever had to *delete* an answer before? (Optional, if Yes) How many have you deleted?

---

Also, big fan here (one of millions, no doubt). Looking forward to seeing you hitting the 2 million milestone within the next decade. ;)

Comment: Probably removing the daily rep cap

Comment: @Adelin I guess Jon's reputation is one of the main reasons the rep cap exists in the first place - otherwise the so team would have to come up with new numbers previously unknown to man :-)

Comment: It was a while back, but...[Revisiting the rep cap (yes, again)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136059)

Answer (score 8):

Question to Jon:

we all know you achieved many great things but will you please consider **sharing an experience where you FAILED at something you tried very hard  to achieve.** Maybe like a rejection from a job interview or from a school you wanted to attend.

> Only those who dare to fail greatly can ever achieve greatly - Robert F. Kennedy

I want to know how you cope with failure. I think that is a virtue that can really benefit me and other developers since failure is inevitable and especially common for new programmers.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Question to Jon:

What was your longest period without answering a question on SO and what was the reason?

Comment: Jon Skeet doesn't answer questions. The questions answer themselves ([5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9147/203057)).

Comment: He already has a queue of answers lined up, they get automatically posted when a matching question is asked. If that doesn't happen in a timely manner, it's a site bug.

Answer (score 5):

Question for Jon: How do you pick the questions you decide to answer? Is your choice based on your expertise, the novelty of the question, or some other metric?

Answer (score 5):

Question:

Have you ever considered teaching (education) as a full-time profession?

*Story behind the question: I was fortunate enough to be part of a [hangouts session in hack summit 2016](https://youtu.be/jGUoF-uByGg), and experienced the skeet way (which is the same as "explain XYZ to me as if I'm 5") of explanation of programming*.

Answer (score 4):

Question to Jon:

<s>How is your day?</s>

Is being a Stack Overflow ruler what you aimed to be or was it just coincidence that you got so much on here?

Answer (score 4):

Questions to Jon: How much time do you spend on SO each day? What does your average day schedule look like? Is there an item for spending time answering programming questions?

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)

A podcast with Jon Skeet

Comment: Do you mean a Stack Overflow podcast episode?

Comment: yes. The one they publish weekly

Answer (score 3):

Do you still consider a rep recalculation would be good as in your question [Revisiting the rep cap (yes, again)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059), in light of the time that has passed since 2012, and how votes evolved?

Like this [trivial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177) earning enough rep to unlock nearly all Stackoverflow privileges?

Answer (score 3):

Question to Jon:

- What have been the main motivations/drivers for you that have resulted in your contribution to software and SO in particular? How do you maintain this motivation?

Answer (score 3):

Question for Jon:

Which StackOverflow question did you spend the most research/time answering and how long did that take?

Answer (score 1):

Question to Jon:

Do you prefer C# or Java ? Why ?

Comment: Take a look at his profile page, the preference question is pretty self-explanatory - you see a whole lot of C-sharp related linkage and questioning going on ;) But then there is this: https://www.quora.com/Why-does-C-s-top-developer-Jon-Skeet-work-in-Java-in-his-day-job

Comment: Well first of all, thanks to respond to my "not that good question", and I also see this interview of 2014. But that's why I wanted to asked Jon, because he doesn't clearly say that he prefers C# over Java, neither does the number of questions or/and answers of C# over the Java's.
And, Java has changed "a lot" since Java 8, and have put in this version some advantage of C#.
But well, I probably am the only one who thought it was a good question ^^'

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any comments on Skeet Bot?

[image: meta Skeet Bot[1]]

Answer (score 0):

Have you found/gained any fortune by answering questions on SO?

Answer (score 0):

_Hi Jon Skeet,

There are many users that want to bit you in your position now!
Maybe a silly question, but Who is the most person here in StackOverflow that you think you are in challenge with him?

Answer (score -6):

Jon, how does your Developer story page look like, particularly this section:

I prefer not to work with _________?

(Just curious to know, even if you have one :))