# Are there any questions posted from Antarctica for Jon Skeet to answer?

Tags: discussion, reputation

On January 14th, Jon Skeet's Stack Overflow reputation [passed one million](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362019/1021259) and on January 15th, the Stack Overflow blog posted [this analysis](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet/) of his answers.

Included in this analysis is this heat map of where the questions Jon Skeet answered have come from:

[image: Jon Skeet answer origin.]

And added below is the note:

> Most of the questions that Jon answers come from users in the United States (28.7%), India (11.1%), and the UK (10.9%). Notice that developers all over the world have gotten help from Jon Skeet, though, on six continents and in over 150 countries. The Stack Overflow community is global, and we all benefit from the worldwide network of programming knowledge being shared here.

Notably lacking from those "six continents" however is Antarctica, which in my opinion, is unacceptable. Now Antarctica is actually assigned IP address ranges, [as seen here](https://lite.ip2location.com/antarctica-ip-address-ranges). However, it might be more useful if anyone who has been there can answer, as it's possible someone accessed through a VPN or behind seven proxies.

Since it is well known that Jon Skeet can answer any question I suppose this question could be better phrased: "Has a question **ever** been asked from Antarctica on Stack Overflow?"

If not, someone should remedy this as soon as possible, preferably before winter.

Comment: Antarctica doesn't show on this heat map? Makes sense.

Comment: Not since Tux the Penguin got sacked by Linus...